How to make the TextField value unique per product?
There is an array of products and for each one there is a textfield with an Int. The problem now is that for each product the value in the textfield is the same (when you change one the other ones change as well) and it needs to be individual. I am not sure how to do it. It is in the last section of the form with the section title "Parts Used per Product".
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import PhotosUI

struct AddPartSheet: View {
    
    
    @State private var partNumber: String = ""
    @State private var name: String = ""
    @State private var rev: String = ""
    @State private var cost: Double = 0
    @State private var stock: Int = 0
    @State private var partsUsedPerProduct: Int = 0
    @FocusState private var Focus: Bool
    @State var selectedPhoto: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State var part: Part
    @Query var products: [Product]
   

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section ("Part Name"){
                    TextField("Part Number", text: $partNumber)
                        .keyboardType(.default)
                        .focused($Focus)
                    TextField("Part Name", text: $name)
                        .focused($Focus)
                }
                Section ("Part Revision"){
                    TextField("Revision", text: $rev)
                        .focused($Focus)
                }
                Section ("Stock"){
                    TextField("Number of parts available", value: $stock, format: .number)
                        .keyboardType(.phonePad)
                        .focused($Focus)
                }
                Section ("Part Cost"){
                    TextField("Cost per Unit", value: $cost, format: .currency(code: "EUR"))
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        .focused($Focus)
                    
                }
                Section ("Parts Used per Product"){
                    ForEach(products.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline){
                            Text(products[index].name)
                            Spacer()
                            TextField("\(name) used per \(products[index].name)", value: $part.partsUsedPerProduct, format: .number)
                                .keyboardType(.phonePad)
                                .focused($Focus)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("New Part")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                    Button("Cancel") { dismiss() }
                }
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Save") {
                        let part = Part(partNumber: partNumber, name: name, rev: rev, stock: stock, cost: cost, partsUsedPerProduct: partsUsedPerProduct, partImage: part.partImage)
                        context.insert(part)
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard){
                    Spacer()
                }
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard){
                    Button {
                        Focus = false
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "keyboard.chevron.compact.down")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
`
import SwiftData
import PhotosUI

@Model
class Part {
    var partNumber: String
    var name: String
    var rev: String
    var stock: Int
    var cost: Double
    var partsUsedPerProduct: Int
    var partImage: Data?
    
    init(partNumber: String, name: String, rev: String, stock: Int, cost: Double, partsUsedPerProduct: Int, partImage: Data?) {
        self.partNumber = partNumber
        self.name = name
        self.rev = rev
        self.stock = stock
        self.cost = cost
        self.partsUsedPerProduct = partsUsedPerProduct
        self.partImage = partImage
    }
}
import SwiftData
import PhotosUI

@Model
class Product {
    var name: String
    var price: Double
    var partsUsed: Int
    var productImage: Data?
    
    init(name: String, price: Double, productImage: Data? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.productImage = productImage
    }
}

I have tried to use $part[index].partsUsedPerProduct but it didn't work and I am not quite sure why and how to proceed as I am learning to program.

partsUsedPerProduct and partsUsed doesn't make sense, you should research and use relationships between your models instead. I am not sure if you want a one-to-many or a many-to-many relationship between Product and Part but I think you need to fix this before you can properly implement your view. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftdata/defining-data-relationships-with-enumerations-and-model-classes and https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata for instance

I forgot to mention that I tried it with the product struct(partsUsed) instead of the part struct(partsUsedPerProduct). I have removed the partsUsed now from product struct.

Not completely but it doesn't matter you should still research how to use realtionships with SwiftData models

I forgot to say, don’t use indices in a ForEach, use the objects instead ForEach(products) { product in …
